# Stylish jquery dialog title to right upper corner of jquery dialog

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-dialog

I well know that how to create a jQuery dialog, moreover I also able to remove title as well as right side close image from the dialog.

But I need to show the title in separate DIV (stylish corner) to right upper corner of dialog.

Is this possible, below is sketch of my requirement. Thanks,
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Of course you can do it.  You just have to play with a lot of css.

The easiest thing to do is find the span that is within the ui-dialog-titlebar, and move it around.  You'll also have to adjust ui-dialog-titlebar as well.

See [here](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/apply-class-on-jquery-ui-dialog-title-bar) for how to modify the dialog title bar.  Basically, the easiest thing to do is as you make your dialog, add a class to the titlebar.  That way you can separately modify the titlebar div and the span it contains with the titlebar text.  You'll obviously need to tweak the css values I gave, since I don't know your actual code, but you'll end up with something like this:

```
$('#dlg').dialog({/*options*/}).parent().find("div.ui-dialog-titlebar").addClass('myClassname');
$('.myClassname span').css({position: "absolute", left: "300px", top: "-10px", background: "red"});
$('.myClassname').css("height", "50px");
```

Comment: @user584018 Why not?  Your dialog itself requires jQuery.  You don't *need* to use jQuery to set all your css styles.  Technically, you don't need it for finding the title bar in the DOM, either, but it's a lot easier to use it.

Comment: please have a look below thread, and please suggest?   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19892242/how-to-replace-jquery-dialog-title-with-custom-div

Comment: @user584018 You haven't upvoted or accepted my answer, nor responded to my feedback.  My suggestion is that you don't ask me to answer another question without first working with me to resolve this one to your satisfaction.

Comment: I am trying your option mean the time, however I would like to thank you. If possible, please reply?

Comment: @ScottMermelstein, check your syntax. You have a `"` that isn't being closed properly: `.find("div.ui-dialog-titlebar')`.

Comment: @jsve Thanks. I fixed that mistake and one on the bottom line as well. Feel free to make changes such as this yourself; you have a high enough reputation to edit things, and it's OK to use that power. If you edit something and people don't like it, they'll just change it back.